# Docker: Development environments

Tags: docker

I am coding in a few different languages/technologies. Actually to be honest, I am only messing around, playing with golang, node.js, ruby on rails, etc.

But now I want to jump on the Docker bandwagon as well, but I am not sure what the benefits would be and if I should put in the effort.

What is the best practise in using Docker for development environments? Do I set up a separate container for each language or technology I dabble with? Or are containers overkill and I should just set up one VM (Linux VM on Windows host) where I do all the development?

How do you guys use Docker for development work?

Comment: This is probably off topic.

Comment: Recently Docker started offering [dev environment feature](https://docs.docker.com/develop/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely go ahead and do that as is the best approach to follow, even if you share volumes between containers, and avoid setting up different VMs if you have the necessary hardware-power in your workstation and do not need to distribute your environment on different workstations.

At my current company, I'm the guy responsible for setting up all the development environments among other things. We have a few monolithic applications but we're quickly decoupling multiple functionalities into separate micro-services.

How we're starting to manage that is, every micro-service code repository has everything self-contained, that being docker-compose files, with a makefile for the automation, tests, etc.

Developers just have to install docker-toolbox on their Mac OS X, clone the repo and type `make`. That will start the docker compose with all the links between the containers and all the necessary bits and pieces (DBs, Caches, Queues).

Direct link to the Makefile: https://github.com/marclop/prometheus-demo/blob/master/Makefile.

Also if you want to avoid setting up all the containers there's a few alternatives out there, for example Phusion's one: https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker.

I hope this answers your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Docker for your development environments, use regular vm's like VirtualBox for that if you want complete separation.
Docker is more suited for delivering finished code somewhere, e.g. to a staging environment.
And the reason is that Docker containers are not ideal for persisted state unless you mess around with sharing volumes.

Comment: I strongly disagree, Docker is fine for dev environments. Handling a few mounts via docker-compose is as simple as it gets.

Comment: This answer is outdated as [docker offers dev environment](https://docs.docker.com/develop/) feature now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is inherently subjective and tied to how you like to do development.  It will also be tied to how you want to deploy these in a testing scenario.

Jonas is correct, the primary purpose of Docker is to provide finished code to a staging/production environment HOWEVER I have used it for development and indeed it may be preferable depending on your situation.

To whit - lets say you have a single virtual server, and you want to minimize the amount of space you are using for your environment.  The entire purpose of Docker is to store a single copy of the Linux kernel (and base software) and re-use them in each docker instance.  You can also minimize the RAM and CPU usage used for running the base Linux "pieces" by running the Docker container on top of Linux.

Probably the most compelling reason (in your case) to use Docker would be to make finding the base setup you want easier.  There are plenty of pre-made docker containers that you can use to build your test/dev environment and deploying your code after you are finished to a different machine is WAY easier using Docker than VMWare or Virtual Box (yes, you can create an OVF and that would work, but Docker is IMHO much easier).

I personally used Project Photon when I was playing around with this, which provided a very easy way to setup the base Docker setup in a VMWare environment.

https://blogs.vmware.com/cloudnative/introducing-photon/

The last time I used Docker was for an assignment in one of my classes where I was having to play around with MongoDB on a local instance.  Setting up MongoDB would have been trivial on either (or both) Windows or Linux, but I felt the opportunity to learn Docker was too much to pass up.  In the end, I feel much more comfortable now with Docker :)

There are ways of backing up Containers, which can (as Jonas pointed out) get kind of messy, but it isn't outside the realm of a reasonably technical individual.

Good Luck either way you go! Again, either way will obviously work - and I don't see anything inherently wrong with either approach.